# how to get Object ID for specific OG object?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads

Action spec: how do I get the list of `object id` for specific object type . for example how do I get the list of "songs" in specific app/page. (I do know how to get list of actions and related objects)

In the example below I would like to give the user the option to "search" for all 'songs' in APP XXX

```
'action_spec':[{'action.type':'music.listens','song':388773468386}, 'APP':'XXXX']}" —
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns all the information you need about a specific OG object

```
$facebook->api('/me/og.follows');
```

of course you need a valid token

Comment: but this is for specific user no? (/me) if i want to create a customer action ad and give the option to promote spesific object , i dont want the campaign manager to enter an ID, i want to give him the option to "search" for it.